# Run Jquery code on Repeater ItemCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

I have a jquery code and i have to run this code for all items in my repeater

In my repeater i have a button and label
what i want is when click a button in repeater send the label parameter to jquery function and run it. My Jquery code is below. it gives error now. Because imgBtnCopy is inside in repeater so it says there is no button with the name imgBtnCopy. So how can i run this code in itemcommand of repeater

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#' + '<%= imgBtnCopy.ClientID %>').zclip({
             path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
             copy: function () {
                 return $('#' + '<%= lblFile.ClientID %>').val();
             },
             afterCopy: function () {

             }
         });

     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ItemCommand` is a server-side event of the repeater object. Since JQuery is client-side code, you have a bit of a mismatch here.

Also, if you view the source of your rendered HTML, you will notice that the error message is correct. There is no object with an id of *imgBtnCopy*. There **will** be objects with *imgBtnCopy* as **part** of the id. The ASP.NET framework will assign a unique id to each control in your `<ItemTemplate>`. Otherwise, you will end up with multiple controls with the same id. Not a good thing.

That being said, you should shift your approach to factor in the information above.

To select all controls that contain *imgBtnCopy* as **part** of their id, use a jquery selector like this:

```
[id*=imgBtnCopy]
```

That way you select all elements that have an id that contains the string *imgBtnCopy*. The *= is the JQuery operator for contains. You would then hook up your JQuery to the click event of each of these buttons.